# Create single mongodb/mongoose connection from cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am making use of SAP Cloud Functions which is similar to any other cloud functions - Google, Azure, Amazon. My use case is very straightforward - User calls the function, function connects to MongoDB Atlas with the connection string, performs CRUD operations, and return results.

I have defined my cloud function as follows -
index.js -

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Address = require('./models/Address')


module.exports = async function (event, context) {
    const mongoConfig = context.getSecretValueJSON('mongodb', 'config.json');
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoConfig.config.uri, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useCreateIndex: true
            });
        console.log("Connected to database")

        
        let address = new Address({
            "city":"wakanda"
        })
        await address.save()
        console.log("Successfully saved address info")
        return address;


    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error - " + error)
        return error
    }
};
```

The corresponding schema and model is defined in a different file -
Address.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
}, { strict: false });

const Address = mongoose.model('Address', addressSchema);

module.exports = Address
```

Now the issue is, every time a call is made to the function, mongoose opens up a new connection to the database, which to me seems like a very inefficient way of doing things. What I would like to know is some pointers on how to organize code so that the connection takes place only once (preferably during the initial deployment of the function).

What I have tried is - defined the connection details in a different file called connection.js -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb:..........',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
```

But now the issue is, I have to hardcode the connection details in the file - connection.js. In the first code snippet, you would see that I made use of a property called -

```
mongoConfig.config.uri
```

This property is available only inside the function and it is defined by the variable `context` which is passed to the cloud function. This property picks the connection details from the environment variable that we define during deployment.

I want to make use of environment variables and not hard code any sensitive information. At the same time make sure, the connection - `mongoose.connect()` is called only once and not every time the function is invoked.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I feel you are targeting too few people. I feel it's not a matter of database, but of "do it once" optimization + environment variable. So, maybe you should generalize your question instead of targeting mongodb, and tag your question sap-cloud-platform instead. Moreover, can you clarify what is your question about the environment variable?

Comment: About the environment variable part - Well, so SAP Cloud function has this capability to set environment variable before deploying the function , so that you can access it during runtime. Access to the environment variable is provided by the **context** variable in the function signature. So my understanding is that, the cloud function executes all the LOC inside the main function however, if something is defined outside of it like the **require** statements above, it executes it only once. But then again, the context variable is available only inside the main function.

Comment: So, I have 2 situations - 1) Access the context variable outside the main function (say right after the require statements) and then call the mongoose.connect (outside the main function), thereby re-using the mongoose connection for all the incoming function calls. OR 2) Continue with the current implementation and place the mongoose.connect inside the main function. I'll be able to access the env variables using the context variable now but the mongoose connection will be created for every new function call.